# how to pass an int-set to sqlserver in a string to stored procedure and use it in an IN-Clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, set, in-clause

I need to call a stored procedure like this:

```
    exec myProcedure '(5, 15, 45)'
```

And inside the procedure I need to use the int-set within an in-Clasue
like this:

```
    SELECT ... FROM table WHERE (days in @intSet)
```

This always bring a syntax Error in the WHERE-Clause.
(SqlServer evidently does not allow to simply replace a part of the statement by a string)

### I plan a solution like this:

I can easily split the integer values of the string into several integers using
CHARINDEX, SUBSTRING, RTRIM, LTRIM, CONVERT - this is not an issue - it works fine.

### But I still cannot figure out into what kind of variable could I then put those integers in order to later use it with the IN-Clause ?

any ideas are greatly appreciated

Gerald

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Pass comma separated string in dynamic query in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344536/how-to-use-pass-comma-separated-string-in-dynamic-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create a split function inside you database,

### Definition Of Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]
    (
      @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
    ) 
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @xml XML
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'

  INSERT INTO @t(val)
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
  RETURN
END
```

### Stored Procedure

Then you would use this split function insdie your Procedure to split the values to be used with In operator.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
    @intSet         VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT * FROM TableName 
  WHERE days IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(@intSet ))

END
```