# SQL Server Query In Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this type of record:

```
Rajkot,Gandhinagar
```

but I want the above record to be changed like the record below.

```
'Rajkot','Gandhinagar'
```

As I want to use IN operator to get result.

Comment: You should not store multiple values in a column.  Use a junction table instead.

Comment: `SELECT '''' + REPLACE('Rajkot,Gandhinagar',',',''',''') +''''`

Comment: @gofr1 I assume he meant something generic .

Comment: @sagi I assumed he want this in a variable and add to some dynamic query.

Comment: another way to do that in your situation is `LIKE` operator. I mean, multiple `LIKE`-s, each one for each record. But it will be slow and messy.

Comment: Gordon is right. Junction table is the best way

Comment: @TedoG. How would you do that with `LIKE` ? . And yes, Gordon solution is the best way,

Comment: @sagi, I mean this, and also said that it's a messy way of doing that:  `WHERE FieldName LIKE '%Rajkot%' OR FieldName LIKE '%Gandhinagar%'`

Comment: Oh, you meant another way to achieve his goal. I thought to add quotes on each value. @TedoG.

Comment: possible duplicate. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344536/how-to-use-pass-comma-separated-string-in-dynamic-query-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using a junction table will usually perform better as noted in the comments.

Nevertheless, assuming you are stuck with the design:

```
TableA
ID      ValueList
1       Uno,Dos,Tres
2       Foo,Bar,Baz,Quux
```

And you want to do the equivalent of this:

```
Select * 
from TableA a
where @Value in ValueList -- ERROR
```

Try this:

```
Select * 
from TableA a
where ','+ValueList+',' like '%,'+@Value+',%'
```

If you want to do this:

```
select * 
from TableA b
where b.Value in (select ValueList from TableA a where a.ID = b.ID)
```

Try:

```
select * 
from TableB b
where exists (
    select 1 from TableA a 
    where a.ID = b.ID and ','+a.ValueList+',' like '%,'+b.Value+',%'
)
```

**Notes on design and performance**: This design prevents any index being used on the column `ValueList`. This may not be a problem if:

- TableA is very small and has very few rows (e.g. < 10 rows). This is because if the data fits into one or two pages, the overhead involved with looking up the index may be greater than the overhead involved in just scanning the page and doing string comparisons.
- Or only a very small subset of rows are actually being searched.
- For example, if you are looking up individual rows by a unique key, or a few tens of rows by an efficient index, and just want to filter based on whether a string is in `ValueList`, this may be faster than a junction table, because the data is held in the same page.
- It may also be faster than filtering client-side (because rows which fail the test don't have to be returned to the client).

In other words, if you are not *searching* by values from this list, but merely *filtering* by them, it may not be worth putting them in to a junction table.

As always one should not be dogmatic about design, but ***test***.

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
select ''''+substring('Rajkot,Gandhinagar',1,charindex(',','Rajkot,Gandhinagar',0)-1)+'''' + ',' +''''+
      substring('Rajkot,Gandhinagar',charindex(',','Rajkot,Gandhinagar',0)+1,len('Rajkot,Gandhinagar'))+''''
```